# HTML table how highlight row on hover except first column?

Tags: html, css

Simple table:

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I like:

[image: table css hover]

Answer (score 6):

Use `:not` and `:first-child` to exclude the first cell like so:

```
#myTable tr:hover td:not(:first-child){
    background: #ddd;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#myTable td {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#myTable tr:hover td:not(:first-child) {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the end goal, target `:hover` on a non `:first-child` element, then also select all of the elements that come after it using the general sibling selector.

```css
td:not(:first-child):hover, td:not(:first-child):hover ~ td {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:first-child` Selector and a `:not`.

For example:

```
#myTable tr:hover td:not(:first-child) {
    background: #999;
}
```

```css
#myTable tr:hover td:not(:first-child) {
    background: #999;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>X</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not` with `:firstchild` like this:

```js
$("#myTable tr").hover(
    function () { $(this).find("td:not(:first-child)").addClass('hoverclass') }, 
    function () { $(this).find("td:not(:first-child)").removeClass('hoverclass') }
);
```

```css
#myTable tr:hover td:not(:first-child)
{
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>X</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>X</td></tr>
</table>
```