# How do I only highlight rows of a table on hover except the last column?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The problem I am facing is similar to this post: [HTML table how highlight row on hover except first column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770244/html-table-how-highlight-row-on-hover-except-first-column). However the replies here are not the effect that I am looking for. I am looking for both the first 2 columns to light up when I hover over either one, and for the 3rd column to not light up anything at all when I hover over it.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Copy any of the answers from the question you linked to and replace `:first-child` with `:last-child`

Comment: @Harrison That was my first thought, but I think the "3rd column to not light up anything at all when I hover over it", might be where the asker is struggling. (Though it's tough to tell without seeing any code)

Comment: you can simply make use of pseudo classes/selector. [Learn here about that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). Anyways you can try

td:not(:last-child):hover{ background-color: red; }

Comment: Possibly: `tr:hover td:not(:last-child)` to hover the whole row

Comment: @freedomn-m read carefully. you cannot do this with css only

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev TBH, no, I didn't read it... :D

Comment: @freedomn-m so if you downvoted my answer that's unfair :)

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev please don't make voting assumptions.   That downvote was *long* before I even read your comment and not by me.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use any [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) nor [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) for this, two [css](/questions/tagged/css) rule's are enough.

Select all the `tr:hover`, and then exclude the last col by using `td:not(:last-of-type)`.

Then disable all [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the last column to disable that triggering the hover.

```css
table>tbody>tr:hover td:not(:last-of-type) {
  background-color: red;
}

table>tbody>tr>td:last-of-type {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<table border cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>o</td>
      <td>o</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>r</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>o</td>
      <td>o</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>r</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry, you are wrong

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev can you explain *why* you think this is wrong?  The snippet *clearly* demonstrates it working perfectly.

Comment: Please clarify @AlexanderNenashev

Comment: @freedomn-m the hover shouldn't react on the 3rd column hover, only a JS solution, sorry guys, check my answer

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @AlexanderNenashev. I've improved my answer.

Comment: seems valid but not sure whether the OP doesn't care about mouse events in the 3rd column